# Why are sin and cos functions in Python not working for me?

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am new to this kind of mathematics and didn't have it in school jet. So my problem is the change from spherical coordinates to a grrid (radius and angle to x and y). First I devide the circle in even angles. Until here everything works. When they get transformed they have all the same distance to the center but seam to be random in rotation. This can be well seen with low numbers like 4.
The final purpose of the project will be to draw a cardioid for that I need a circle with points. So here my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
import round_canvas as round

#settings
speed = 1 # in ms
window_size = 700
cellamount = 20
cell = window_size / cellamount
r = 300
pointSize = 20
animationSize = window_size - cell*4

#colors:
#48979b
#7cbeba
#a7c7b3
#d9beac
#f5e6d9

#window
win = Tk()
win.title("heart")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.geometry(str(window_size) + "x" + str(window_size))
win.configure(background="#f5e6d9")

# variables
point_amount = 4
point_cords = [] # saves point rotations in list (place in list coresponds to number of point)

# canvas
canvas = Canvas(win, width=window_size, height=window_size, bg="#f5e6d9", 
highlightthickness=0)
canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
canvas_overlay = round.round_rectangle(canvas, cell, cell, cell*cellamount-cell, 
cell*cellamount-cell, radius=40, fill="#d9beac")

# functions:
def drawPoints():
    for point in range(0, point_amount):
        #print(point)
        localPoint = 360/(point_amount)*point
        point_cords.append(localPoint)

def showPoints():
    for angle in point_cords:
        print(angle)
        localX = cos(angle)*r+window_size/2 # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5wjXoFrau4&t=635s
        localY = sin(angle)*r+window_size/2
        print(localX, localY)
        visiblePoint = canvas.create_oval(localX-pointSize/2, localY-pointSize/2, localX+pointSize/2, localY+pointSize/2, width=0, fill="#7cbeba")

# main
def main():
    drawPoints()
    showPoints()

win.after(speed,main)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's trig functions take their angles in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees.

You can easily convert between the two units using [`math.radians`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians) and [`math.degrees`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.degrees).

```
>>> math.sin(math.radians(45))
0.7071067811865476
```

Comment: That's true for every language I know: C, C++, C#, Java, Kotlin, Python, R.  I've never heard of any language implement trig functions to take degrees as input.